# Propel Orm - propel command is not recognized

Tags: php, composer-php, propel

I am new to propel ORM. I have installed propel through composer. Its inside `myproject/vendor/bin`. I created the **schema.xml** and the **propel.json** inside `myproject/includes`.

Now how do I run the propel sql:build command?

If i run from myproject/vendor/bin - it says no schema to build.

If I run from myproject/includes - It says propel Command is not recognized.

I am using windows 7. Should I have to include in environment variables path. If so should I have to do this for every project?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could edit your question and add the following: Which package did you add (name and version)? Which commands did you enter on the command line exactly? Have you considered being in the directory containing your data file and calling the command with a relative path to the `bin` directory?

Comment: I used propel 2.0. I read in the documents. It sais that I have to set the path for the propel command in vendor/bin for windows. Now its working.

Answer (score 0):

This is old but you can also use `"./vendor/bin/propel" sql:build` etc on Windows, if you don't want to be adding random project folders to your PATH.